# BASH чтение файла и его вывод

Tags: linux, bash, debian, sh

Есть написанный код на bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do  
clear
FILE="/root/.core/config.txt"
while read LINE; do
    SERVER=$LINE
    SCREENID=$(screen -ls | grep -w $SERVER | cut -f 2)
    if [ $SCREENID ]; then
        echo "ДА $LINE ДА"
    else
        echo "123 $LINE 456"
    fi
done < $FILE
sleep 3
done
```

И при выводе данных из файла, получается некорректный вывод данных в терминале:
[image: консоль терминала]
Мне надо чтобы выводило так:

1. 123 bungee 456
2. 123 auth 456
3. 123 lobby 456
4. 123 dayz 456

В интернете не нашел принцип вывода данных из файла.Надеюсь на помощь.

p.s config.txt:

> [image: конфиг]

Comment: В вопрос желательно добавить  - как выглядит файл config.txt, так же уточнить редактировали ли его через windows

Comment: @PotroNik добавил config.txt, насчет редактирования - нет, как создал на самом сервере файл, так все, только добавил строчки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тут `\r` в конце строки. потому и курсор перекидывает в начало для вывода 456.

```
(tr -d '\r' | while read LINE; do
 echo "123 $LINE 456";
 done) < $FILE
```

Comment: недавно мучался также.. плейлист тв надо было перепарсить на прокси.

Comment: проще файл сразу от возврата каретки почистить чем нибудь вроде `sed -i 's/\r//g' $FILE`

Comment: Он тогда в винде поедет в одну строчку.

Comment: В конце возвращать каретку обратно)) автор писал что в винде файл не открывал, а создал его на сервере.

Comment: на скриншоте виндовая програмка. все врут(с)

Comment: @eri я открыл файл для показа, а сам файл редачил через putty

Comment: тем не менее улетевшиен в начало 456 - это `\r` и ничто другое

Comment: улетевшиен - жесть как опечатался) или клава эта майкрософтская.